# Webpack2 Alias not working with Angular2 components

Tags: angular, webpack-2

I'm using webpack@2.2.0-rc.4 to serve NG2 project. Linking my modules only works  using relative paths. The absolute paths are not working.

This is how the resolve is configured

```
 config.resolve = {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html'],
    };
```

this is how i link the files from `src/app/app.module.ts`

```
import { Child } from 'app/components/child/add-child.component';
```

and i get `Cannot find module` even if my there is a class in `src/app/components/child/add-child.component.ts`.

My folder structure looks like this

```
src
-- app
   -- app.module.ts
   -- components
      -- child
         -- add-child.component.ts
```

**UPDATE 1**

If i try to import the file with another path like `./app/components/add-child.component` i get a more complex error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/components/child/add-child/add-child.component' in '/Users/stefanosergio/rep/webapp/src/app'
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 18:28-91
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/main.ts
```

Plus the good old

```
Cannot find module './app/components/child/add-child/add-child.component'.
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have `"baseUrl": "./src",` in the `tsconfig`, not sure this is the right value but changing it doesnt really improve anything.

Comment: have you tried `import { Child } from './app/components/child.component';` ?

Comment: I tried now, still no luck but i updated the question.

Comment: in which file you are importing ? share your folder structure please.

Comment: Ok i added the folder structure